# Select de itens duplicados MySQL

Tags: sql, mysqli, sql-select

Tenho uma tabela de registro de `evento`, nela registro um `id` do evento, `data`, `id_contrato` que passou pelo evento, e `tipo` do evento. Esbarrei com um problema que é, alguns `contratos` tem o mesmo `tipo` de evento registrado duas vezes nessa tabela exemplo:

```
(02, 2021-09-11 10:52:00, 232323, Suspensao)

(02, 2021-09-11 12:00:00, 232323, Suspensao)
```

A questão é que esse tipo de evento não funciona no sistema, pois a nova suspensão esta condicionada a uma ativação ou vice e versa. Mas, no banco de dados (que é o que reflito em um relatório) esse registro ocorre, e o relatoria acaba por não ser confiável. Queria realizar um `select` condicionando evento + data exemplo:

```
select * from tbl_eventos
where
day(data)= day(data) (mesmo dia) and evento like "suspensao"
```

Ou seja identificar as suspensões que tem a mesma `data`.

Comment: Não seria melhor usar `AND`... `select * from tbl_eventos where day(data)= day(data)  AND tipo_evento="suspensao"`

Comment: Foi um erro na digitação era para ser and mesmo, mas está parte que enviei foi minha primeira tentativa que falhou xD

Comment: Ainda não ficou claro a dificuldade

Comment: o que quer não é agrupar por data? um `group by` apenas na data ignorando os minutos não resolve?

Comment: @RicardoPontual, eu tentei fazer o uso do group by mas estava me retornando erro 1055, e a tbl em questão vem contida com essas infomações de hora também, então teria que utilizar alguma função de data.

Comment: foi o que eu disse no comentário *"data ignorando os minutos"* :) já tentou `GROUP BY DATE(data)`?

Comment: Se as horas forem irrelevantes pode converter o timestamp pra date: Exemplo to_date(data)